# Update elements lesser x in a range

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

Suppose we have some array like 2,34,3,5,8,12,-1,44, 56.
And I have a set of queries in advance to find an amount of elements < given x from some segment. Like all numbers less than 30 on fragment 0,2 will answer 2 for 2,3 from 2,34,3... Fenwik tree provides the functionality.
But now I want to more: on every query to modify: set all elements less than 30 on segment 0,2 to -1. SO, the array turns into:
-1,34,-1,5,8,12,-1,44, 56.
Obviously the order of quires is important.
I suspect that there is no such thing, but would be happy to hear it from the wise men of the forum. Great thank, Levi

Comment: 1. Are you sure a solution exists? 2. What is the format of each query? Is ```x``` and ```y``` same across all queries? 3. Add an example

Comment: 1. Not sure 2. x and y are not the same through queries 3. 1,2,3,8,2,5, 25, -1  Change on interval with indexes from 3 to 6 all numbers under 3 to 1000. Makes 1,2,3,8,1000,5, 25, -1

Comment: The problem here is that the order of the queries is important, in case there are several queries (not clear from the post). Please provide important details in the post itself, not in comments.

Comment: Explained better. IMHO at least